# Detect if a key other than "this" key has been pressed

Tags: unity, c#, input, keyboard

I'm wondering if there is a way to detect if the key being pressed is NOT matching a specific `KeyCode`.

I tried using: `!(Input.GetKeyDown(exampleKeyCode))`, but that also detects if the key is being released.

I also tried using
`(!(Input.GetKeyDown(exampleKeyCode)) && !(Input.GetKeyUp(exampleKeyCode))` 
but that doesn't work because when a key is not down it is up, and when it is not up it is down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[You can first check whether "any" key has been pressed](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-anyKeyDown.html), then check if the key you're listening to has *not*, to respond only to presses that were *not* that key.

```cs
if (Input.anyKeyDown) {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(exampleKeyCode)) {
        Debug.Log("The example key (and maybe others) was pressed this frame");
    } else {
        Debug.Log("One or more keys were pressed this frame, but not the example key.");
    }
}
```

Note however that `anyKeyDown` does not reset until all keys have been released. So if I hold <kbd>A</kbd> it will return `true` once. If I then press <kbd>B</kbd> while still holding <kbd>A</kbd>, it will continue reading `false`. Only once I release all keys then press a key in that "no keys held" state will it fire `true` again.

If you want to more robustly identify all key presses that were not "this" key, even while a key is held, you can switch to Unity's new Input System package, which is more powerful. [There's a thread here discussing ways to implement this kind of functionality with that package](https://forum.unity.com/threads/check-if-any-key-is-pressed.763751/).

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of that!